# How do I check my gcc C++ compiler version for my Eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, fedora

I'm using Eclipse release version 3.7.0, but I can't find the gcc anywhere. How and where can I see the version of gcc I'm currently using?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Just type

```
gcc --version
```

in any terminal near you.. ;-)

Comment: thanks for your ans. so the gcc comes with the OS itself and not the Eclipse program? as in the gcc version will depends on the OS version?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is just a glorified editor. The compiler is the command-line driven `gcc` (or it could be the `clang` command); there probably is a way to configure Eclipse to tell it which compiler should it use (or to tell it to use the `make` builder to compile programs). You can have installed several versions of `gcc` ...

Answer (score 29):

```
gcc -dumpversion
```

> `-dumpversion` Print the compiler version (for example, `3.0`) — and don't do anything else.

The same works for following compilers/aliases:

```
cc -dumpversion
g++ -dumpversion
clang -dumpversion
tcc -dumpversion
```

Be careful with automate parsing the GCC output:

- Output of `--version` might be localized (e.g. to Russian, Chinese, etc.)
- GCC might be built with option [--with-gcc-major-version-only](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html). And some distros (e.g. [Fedora](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45168516/1661465)) are already using that
- GCC might be built with option [--with-pkgversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html). And `--version` output will contain something like `Android (5220042 based on r346389c) clang version 8.0.7` (it's real version string)

Comment: Thank you. It's what exactly I need. I need to get version of gcc at my script, so don't wanna parse output of `gcc --version` which contains bunch of information.

Comment: Thanks. And `-dumpfullversion` is useful for me.

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  printf("gcc version: %d.%d.%d\n",__GNUC__,__GNUC_MINOR__,__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answers the question **How and where can I see the version of gcc I'm currently using?** simply running this code we can find the **gcc version**

Comment: Yes, currently. Not the version it was compiled with.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but I was looking for this, so thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is:

```
gcc --version
```

Rather than searching on forums, for any possible option you can always type:

```
gcc --help
```

haha! :)

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `gcc -v` command that works like `gcc --version` and if you would like to now where  `gcc` is you can use `whereis gcc` command

I hope it'll be usefull