# gcc 7.1.1 on Fedora 26 dumpversion now only includes major version by default

Tags: version, gcc7

After upgrading from Fedora 25 to 26 the default gcc version is now version 7.1.1 and the output of `gcc -dumpversion` has changed from major.minor.patch to just major.

new output:

```
$ gcc -dumpversion
7
```

The manual states

> -dumpversion
>
> Print the compiler version (for example, 3.0, 6.3.0 or 7)—and don’t do
>   anything else. This is the compiler version used in filesystem paths,
>   specs, can be depending on how the compiler has been configured just a
>   single number (major version), two numbers separated by dot (major and
>   minor version) or three numbers separated by dots (major, minor and
>   patchlevel version).

I have not found where to change this compiler configuration to include the three numbers configured with dots.  The closest I have found is the major version only configuration:

> --with-gcc-major-version-only Specifies that GCC should use only the major number rather than major.minor.patchlevel in filesystem paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some research I found the configure the version is a compile time option (if you compile the compiler from source).

I also found that there is a new `gcc -dumpfullversion` option that will provide the full version number, ie 7.1.1 which is what our build system expects. Small caveat is that `-dumpfullversion` is not supported on older versions of gcc.

So we had to change the build system to get the version via `gcc -dumpversion` and check if its a single digit and if so then substitute `-dumpfullversion` to get the full major.minor.patch gcc version.

Answer (score 21):

I used both options together:

```
gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion
```

This seems to work on old and new in a uniform way:

```
[root@zeta ~]# gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion
```

4.4.7

```
[jenkins@build-el7 ~]$ gcc -dumpfullversion -dumpversion
```

7.2.1

Comment: It appears gcc ignores `-dump*` args it doesn't recognise, and stops processing args once it does recognise one. That's why this works, and why `-dumpfullversion` must be first!